# Cannot find a Repository Form

Tags: directory, repository, delphi-10.4-sydney

I've added a form to the Repository. (Created a blank form with a button, saved it, right-click Add to Repository). But I cannot get to it. *File | New | Other* doesn't offer it.
[image]

My default folders has

[image]

but the new form is saved here in a *roaming* folder:

[image]

Has some link has got screwed up? Can I restore some default somehow?

Comment: Are the files (YourForm.pas and YourForm.dfm) missing in M:\Delphi_Sydney\MyRepository?

Comment: All there is there is Repository.xml. That contains   ...  </Item>  <Item IDString="M:\Delphi_Sydney\64Work\wsm\FormWithButtonU" CreatorIDString="BorlandDelphiRepositoryCreator">
      <Name Value="WSForm"/> ...
      <Icon Value=""/>
      <Description Value="a form with a button"/>
      <Author Value="MS"/>  .I think the problem is Delphi isn't using Repository.xml there but the one in the Roaming folder. Surely they should match?